# condition for $f \in H^{1/2} \cap C^0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I need to show that for $f \in H^{1/2}(S^1) \cap C^0(S^1)$ we have :
$$  \iint\limits_{S^1 \times S^1}{ \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^2}{\sin^2(\pi(x-y))}dx dy}< + \infty $$
and that, conversely, if $f$ is a function in $C^0(S^1)$ verifying this equation, then $f \in H^{1/2}(S^1) \cap C^0(S^1)$.

[EDIT : the first part is done] For the first part I want to take advantage of the fact that $f \in H^{1/2}(S^1) \cap C^0(S^1)$ implies that the partial Fourier sums of $f$ converge uniformly towards $f$ (from a previous exercise...). Therefore I need to show that this integral, replacing $f$ by $S_nf$, is bounded by a constant not depending of $n$. With the uniform convergence, the bound on $S_nf$ then gives the bound on $f$.

Everything looks good then, but I need to have a $O(n)$ bound on the following integral :  $\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}{ \frac{\sin^2(nx)}{\sin^2(x)}dx}$ which I am having trouble getting...

For the other question, I tried to use the fact that the Cesaro partial Fourier sums converge uniformly towards a continuous function, but then I get lost in the calculations...

So two questions :

- is there a good way of bounding $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin^2(nx)}{\sin^2(x)}dx$ by $n$ (I tried to cut the integral in $n$ pieces but unsuccessfuly) [EDIT : this is done]
- Any advice for the second part ?

Comment: Ok so i managed to get the bound I wanted finally ! just cutting the integral as I said and bounding separately the extreme ones (where sin = 0) and the others.
The second part remains :)

Comment: Something does not quite look right here. The integral you give is almost the definition of the Sobolev-Slobedecki norm, expect that the sine function has zero other than for x=y. Is this really what you intend?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I apologize for commenting here. I'd try to prove $||P_{k}f||_2 \lesssim 2^{-k/2-\epsilon}$, where $P_k$ is a projection to frecuencies $\sim 2^k$ (a projection is a bump function supported near $n\sim 2^k$). As projections the characteristic functions work, but they could be complicated to use, so I recommend to "smooth" them, like in the Féjer kernel. Anyway, you have $P_{k}f(x) = \phi_{k}*f(x) = \int (f(x-y)-f(x))\phi_{k}(y)\,dy$ for $k\neq 0$ since $\hat{\phi_{k}}(0)=0$, so
$$
|f*\phi_{k}(x)|^2 \le (\int |f(x-y)-f(x)||\phi_k(y)|\,dy)^2 = (\int |f(z)-f(x)||\phi_k(x-z)|\,dz)^2.
$$
Here you may use Cauchy-Schwarz and try to control $|\phi_k(y)|$ using $1/\sin^2y$. I hope this helps. Have a nice day!